# Allow Notification Access to Android Application without starting a android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-settings, notification-listener

I have created an application for accessing **notifications** using `NotificationListenerService`, but first I have to allow **notification access** manually to read notifications by starting another android `Activity` using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there any way that I can enable notification access automatically or provide a **gps** like Yes | No `Dialog` to enable/disable it?